# Using Powershell export-csv to save like Excel csv

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to use PowerShell functions to save Excel xlsx files to csv files.  So I am using the below command:

```
`PS> Import-Excel "jj.xlsx" | export-csv -Path "jj.csv" -NoTypeInformation`
```

In the Excel file I have a date and "time" field that I receive from my users.
The excel file shows:

```
Date         Time
10/28/2020   3:45 PM
11/23/2020   PM
```

In Excel I save the file as a CSV file, the output shows:

```
Date, Time, ...
10/28/2020,3:45 PM, ...
11/23/2020,PM, ...
```

When I try to use the above PowerShell commands above, the csv file looks like:

```
"Date","Time", ...
"10/28/2020 12:00:00 AM", "0.65625", ...
"11/23/2020 12:00:00 AM", "PM", ...
```

(Converted the time entered in first record to a fractional number)

Should I be using parameters in the Export-csv command to make it look like what Excel provides when saving as a csv file?

I figure it must be something easy.   I'm new to Powershell, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,